# Compact pbf vector tiles back to bundles from exploded vtpk

Tags: arcpy, pbf, vtpk

There is a great method available in ArcGIS Pro (ArcPy) [arcpy.management.ExtractPackage](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/extract-package.htm) to extract vtpk package including *exploding bundle files Esri uses to pack standard pbf vector tiles* together for each zoom level.

Is there a way to do the opposite - either take the whole directory to package back to standard vtpk, or at least compact all pbf files for each zoom level into appropriate bundles?

Why: Possibility of incremental updates. Instead of application downloading the whole new 10GB vtpk, only the 10MB package of updated pbf tiles can be downloaded and swapped.

I am aware of [openvtpk](https://github.com/syncpoint/openvtpk) which converts vtpk completely into mbtiles with style etc. So clearly it is able to read properly bundles and extract them into pbf, but does not offer reverse function as far as I can see in the code, anyway this is the closest useful thing I got to so far.

I am aware of [raster-tiles-compactcache](https://github.com/Esri/raster-tiles-compactcache) documentation, which I tried to apply on my exploded pbf files. I have created a bundle for one sample level which then I tried to swap inside of unexploded vtpk. But without success. Important to say the bundle generated this way had very different size to the original bundle.